# Is there dancing at a divorcee's wedding

Tags: halacha, marriage, divorce, dance

When a divorcee gets remarried, is there dancing at the wedding or is this prohibited?

Comment: Hi MonOve! [Edit]ing in to the question why you think it might be prohibited would greatly improve this question.

Comment: Not everything that is not done is not not done because it's prohibited, some things are just inappropriate from a Hashkafah perspective. That was my question.

Comment: Well, whatever you were thinking, it would serve you well to explain exactly what you are looking for in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to J.SE!

The Talmud prescribes extra blessings to be said at any after-parties held several days after the wedding; if it's an "encore wedding" (as Miss Manners would say), that period is a few days shorter.

But as for the dancing at the wedding itself, it's really a matter of taste decided by the people involved. My impression is the most common thing is to have dancing, but a much smaller crowd. (My father once attended a second marriage where the emcee announced, "Ladies and gentlemen, for the first time, Mr. & Mrs. Joe Schwartz!"<sup>1</sup> and my father thought - er um, no not really.) I spoke with a very seasoned rabbi who said he's seen second weddings that ranged from very quiet affairs to all-out bashes on par with a typical first wedding.

<sup>[1] (not actual name)</sup>

Comment: 1 instead of 7 seems like more than a few.